# JavaScript executed through address bar is not working in Firefox 7, 8

Tags: firefox, javascript

JavaScript executed through address bar is not working in Firefox 7, 8. For example, the code below works in Chrome, when I paste it into the address bar and press `Enter`:

```
javascript:alert("hello world!");
```

In the latest Firefox, it's not working. Why? How can I make it work?

Comment: What is your practical application of that feature?

Comment: You can find answer here. http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/885558

Comment: i cant find any solution from your url

Comment: i just need to run javascript through adress bar

Comment: [See this other question about the behavior.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375288/firefox-6-javascript-in-addressbar)

Comment: From that URL: "Starting in Firefox 6 javascript in the url-bar runs with a null security principal for security reasons. This means it's almost disabled. **You need a bookmarklet or an add-on** for a workaround."

Comment: You can run Javascript using Firebug.

Comment: The feature has been disabled in Firefox.

Comment: is there any other way to make it work???? other than addon

Comment: You need a bookmarklet or an add-on for a workaround.

Comment: no i just wanna make it simple...i know some work around is there for it

Comment: @Vishnu Opening the browser's JavaScript console is simple... I don't understand...

Comment: ctrl+shift+k ??

Comment: @Vishnu [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: @imeVidas: My application is using keywords to modify the URL or the page in the same manner as a bookmarklet, but without manually clicking or cluttering up the toolbar with bookmarklet icons.  Anyone have a solution for this?  There's no way to disable the disabler in `about:config`?

Answer (score 3):

It's a security issue.
Other browsers will follow this restriction...

Use firebug instead ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute javascript from url, then you have to use like this:

let's say, you have site: http://www.site.com/post.php.
then in post.php, insert:

```
if (!empty($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == myfunction ){
echo '<script>alert("Hi User");</script>';
}
```

after that, when you enter: http://www.site.com/post.php?action=myfunction

then the script will be shown.